# Microsoft Transact SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can anyone please explain this query? I searched into the Microsoft docs but not able to find what is the role of INCLUDE keyword here.

```
IF {INCLUDE [column1] : SUM([column2])} > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Hi BALA. This does not appear to me as T-SQL. Perhaps this is from a report? Can you describe your context a bit more?

Comment: I got this query from a customer, trying to replicate it in SQL. We can assume column1 here as some ID and column2 as amount.

Comment: I do not know the answer to this question and am a Linux guy, so I cannot even test. However, the syntax above seems to mean that you check whether `column1` is higher than 0 and evaluate the expression to 1 if so, 0 if not. If column1 happens to not have a value, then it's defaulted to sum(colummn2). However, this is not SQL code, I wonder what this is, maybe some Excel-like formula.

Comment: *"am a Linux guy, so I cannot even test"* SQL Server has been available on Linux since 2017 @LajosArpad . ;) Though I agree, the above is *not* T-SQL.

Comment: It looks like the statement is from Tableu - see here: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_include.htm